# Google omaha build error

Tags: build, scons

I'm getting a few warnings and fatal error when I try to build omaha on windows 10 machine.

```
C:\updater\omaha\omaha>hammer
scons: warning: No installed VCs
File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_init.py", line 426, in SiteInitMain

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_init.py", line 426, in SiteInitMain
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: No installed VCs
File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_tools\target_platform_windows.py", line 283, in generate

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_tools\target_platform_windows.py", line 283, in generate
Using precompiled headers.
Building versions: 1.3.99.0
python C:\chromium\upd\omaha\omaha\tools\proxy_clsid_utils.py
AttributeError: SConsEnvironment instance has no attribute 'WiX':
  File "C:\chromium\upd\omaha\omaha\main.scons", line 992:
    BuildEnvironments(_environments)
  File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_init.py", line 276:
    e.ExecuteDefer()
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Environment.py", line 224:
    return apply(self.method, nargs, kwargs)
  File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_tools\defer.py", line 171:
    func(fenv)
  File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_init.py", line 203:
    exports={'env': ec}, duplicate=0)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 553:
    return apply(_SConscript, [self.fs,] + files, subst_kw)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 262:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "C:\chromium\upd\omaha\omaha\recovery\build.scons", line 104:
    env.BuildSConscript('repair_exe')
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Environment.py", line 224:
    return apply(self.method, nargs, kwargs)
  File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_tools\environment_tools.py", line 191:
    env.SConscript(script_file, exports={'env': env.Clone()})
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 553:
    return apply(_SConscript, [self.fs,] + files, subst_kw)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 262:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "C:\chromium\upd\omaha\omaha\recovery\repair_exe\build.scons", line 37:
    env.BuildSConscript(subdir)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Environment.py", line 224:
    return apply(self.method, nargs, kwargs)
  File "C:\chromium\upd\swtoolkit\site_scons\site_tools\environment_tools.py", line 191:
    env.SConscript(script_file, exports={'env': env.Clone()})
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 553:
    return apply(_SConscript, [self.fs,] + files, subst_kw)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.3.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 262:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "C:\chromium\upd\omaha\omaha\recovery\repair_exe\msp\build.scons", line 156:
    old_msi, new_msi = CreateMsiInstallerFiles(
  File "C:\chromium\upd\omaha\omaha\recovery\repair_exe\msp\build.scons", line 60:
    old_unsigned_output = old_unsigned_env.WiX(
```

I spent a lot of time debugging warnings and seems scons 1.3.1 doesn't support visual studio 2015, however google's build 
[instructions](https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/doc/DeveloperSetupGuide.md) imply opposite. Also it's not fully clear whether the error depends on the warnings. Please help to solve the issue.

Comment: I don't see why you would use an ancient version like SCons 1.3.1 (the newer ones *do* support VS2015) when the build instructions you cite above don't explicitly require it...ah, reading a second time they actually do. My bad. That's strange and shouldn't really give a lot of problems. At least I would always give it a first try anyways.

Comment: @dirkbaechle I tried a newer version of SCons, omaha's hammer doesn't build with it so a lot of changes should be done I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, turns out a new version of wix toolset has bin folder with all the utils and official docs and tutorial contains wrong environment variable. By the way the warnings have no impact on build process at all.
So probably there is no point to debug any code in similar situations, just need to check the environment.

Comment: Can you talk more about how you fix the problem? I downloaded WiX 3.10.3 and put it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin`, and I received the same error. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, please check the OMAHA_WIX_DIR environment variable, it should have bin folder in the path, once I changed it to target wix binaries it worked

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have `set OMAHA_WIX_DIR=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin` inside `hammer.bat`, I downloaded `wix310.exe` and installed it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10`. Inside `WiX Toolset v3.10\bin` I have `wix.dll`, `WixCop.exe` etc.. Are they the binary files you are referring to? I am still receiving the same error /.\ What should I change to?

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally solve it by adding `win_env.AppendENVPath('PATH', (_sdk_dir + '\\bin\\' +
    _sdk_version + '\\x86'))` to `main.scons`